# Android Publisher API Purchases Subscriptions Get 403

Tags: android, google-api

I'm trying to validate receipts using Google's API, but I am running into an issue where hitting this request.

`https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/packageName/purchases/subscriptions/subscriptionId/tokens/token`

returns  "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console."

but

`https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/packageName/inappproducts`

returns the list of products which makes me believe I have authorization right, but just can't pinpoint why I can't get individual subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

I had to go into that product, make a small change, and saved. That fixed the API.